# Find period of the following function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find period of :

$$f(x)=| \sin(x) + \cos(x) |$$

Attempt:
Let $$f(x)=|\sin x +\cos x|\tag{I}$$
Let $t$ be the required period,
So,

$f(x)=f(x+t)$

Putting $x=0$ we get,

$f(0)=f(t)$

f(0)=1 (from 'I')

Now we have the following,

$1=| \sin t + \cos t |$

If we put $t=\pi/2$ ,that would satisfy the equation. But when I put $t=\pi/2$ in $f(x+t)$,

I do not get $f(x)$ ,that means $\pi/2$ is not the period of the function. What I have done wrong?

Comment: It must be the half of the period of sinus because all negative part becomes positive.

Comment: If I don't know the graph of this function then how can I figure out the period

Comment: @user190625 solution of your equation is also $t=\pi$ and $t=3\pi /2$ and $t=2\pi $

Comment: @ChristianF thanks alot sir

Comment: Where do you think the summand $\pi$ in $f(x+\pi)$ comes from to the person to whom you have given the maximum approval?

Comment: To answer your question, suppose period is $\pi/2$. Then $f(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}$ and $f(3\pi/4) = 0$. So $f(x) = f(x+t)$ at just one point is not sufficient. We need $f(x) = f(x+t)$ for all $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=| \sin(x) + \cos(x) | =\sqrt{2}\Big|\sin(x+{\pi\over 4})\Big|$$

Now $$f(x+\pi) = \sqrt{2}\Big|\sin(x+{\pi\over 4}+\pi)\Big| = \sqrt{2}\Big|\sin(\pi-(x+{\pi\over 4}+\pi))\Big|$$
$$=\sqrt{2}\Big|\sin(-x-{\pi\over 4})\Big|= \sqrt{2}\Big|-\sin(x+{\pi\over 4})\Big|=f(x)$$

So the peroid of $f$ is $\pi$.

Comment: Please tell what I have done wrong in my attempt

Comment: And if we draw a graph it is easy to see that $\pi$ is minimal period.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\sin(x) + \cos(x)=K\sin(x+\theta)=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$. Hint: expanding the right hand side. $\pi$ is the period of $f(x)=|\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})|$ because $\sin(x)$ is positive in $(2m\pi,(2m+1)\pi)$, negative in $((2m+1)\pi,2(m+1)\pi)$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

$|\sin(x)|$ then has period $\pi$ as the negative part becomes positive. Note that $f(x)=|\sin(x) + \cos(x)|=|\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})|$ is just a scaled and shifted version of $|\sin(x)|$.

Comment: What's wrong in my method please tell

Comment: $f(x)=1$ when $x=0,\pi /2$ and $ \pi$.

Comment: So we take the least value of t that also satisfy the equation f(x+t)

Comment: And that you want $f(x+t)=f(x)$, there's something left behind when you take $t=\pi /2$, so it won't be the answer.

Comment: So generally the values of t that satisfy the function need not to be the period of that function.

Comment: Yes. You're just unlucky that the equation gives you 3 solutions in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Ok thanks alot for helping me out.

Comment: np. Note that $2\pi$ is also a period of $f(x)$. What you're doing is finding the fundamental period, where you take the least among all possible periods.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you do not know the shape of the graphs but want to find the period. We will assume that you can evaluate the functions and know the sum and difference formulas for sine and cosine.
\begin{eqnarray}
 |\sin x+\cos x|&=&|\sin(x+t)+\cos(x+t)|\\
&=&|\sin x\cos t+\cos x\sin t+\cos x\cos t-\sin x\sin t|\\ 
&=&|\sin x\cos t+\cos x\sin t+\cos x\cos t+\sin x\sin t-2\sin x\sin t|\\
&=&|(\sin x+\cos x)(\sin t+\cos t)-2\sin x\sin t|
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\sin\pi=0$ and $\cos\pi=-1$we see that when $t=\pi$ we get

$$|(\sin x+\cos x)(\sin \pi+\cos \pi)-2\sin x\sin \pi|=|-(\sin x+\cos x)|$$

But $|-(\sin x+\cos x)|=|\sin x+\cos x|=f(x)$

Comment: Ok thanks alot sir for helping me out

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: $\mid \sin x + \cos x\mid$ will have the same period as $(\sin x + \cos x)^2 = 1 + \sin{2x}$. Period of $\sin{2x} = 2\pi/2 = \pi$